# How get Cassandra, Spring Boot to call field setters for an entity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data

I have an entity that is grabbed from Cassandra by a repository. In it are some custom fields that I want set when certain managed fields are set by Spring/Cassandra.

But when I try to put the primary key signifier on the getter method (similar to JPA) it doesn't use the methods. How do I get it to call them when setting the fields?

```
@Table(name="entity")
public class MyEntity {
    private String calculatedField;
    private CompoundKey pk;

    ...elided...

    @PrimaryKey
    public void setPk(CompoundKey pk) {
        this.pk = pk;

        //do some calculations...
        this.calculatedField = pk.getField() + val;
    }
}
```

This always leaves `calculatedField` as null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `AccessType` annotation is exactly for that purpose.](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/annotation/AccessType.html)
Your entity should look like this:

```
@AccessType(Type.PROPERTY) 
public class MyEntity {
    //...
}
```

Comment: This is the answer, but could you update the answer to specify that it needs to be put on the class like this: `@AccessType(Type.PROPERTY) public class MyEntity` (but obviously with line breaks)